# Real Time Dashboard - Data refresh issue

Tags: java, api, real-time, dashboard

I want to build an dashboard to visualize data from multiple database through an API. I don't want to pull data at regular interval because each database have individual API so I need to pull from 25 different servers.

I need some solution to push from server side to the dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to push data realtime from server to client can be done through Webockets. Using WebSockets you can push data from the server to the client without the client having to poll the server for updates.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I need some other options than web sockets. It will be helpful if you suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kafka. Let all databases write to some specific Kafka topic. Your application will read messages from this topic when it needs to. Thus, you will get rid of the need to write different queries for different databases.